# Ubuntu Partition being shown unallocated, and after running Boot Repair tool GRUB disappeared

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, boot-repair

Yesterday, I extended the C drive in Windows. Due to some restrictions, I had to move some partitions to the right side (using third party software) so that I can merge the C drive with the immediate right partition. But some error occurred when I tried booting up after extending the C drive. I entered the GRUB shell and even after running `ls` for every disc partition, I was unable to find the root directory of Ubuntu. I tried every basic command in GRUB shell but to no avail. Then, I ran Boot-Repair ([results](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sVsYWFVwks/)), but it deleted the GRUB entry from the Boot-Menu. I'm guessing the partition record is missing because even Windows is showing the partition unallocated. I have attached the results of the Boot Repair. I'm stuck at the moment. I can not format the drive as it contains important data. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You show no LInux partitions. All the partitions are NTFS for Windows or other required Windows partitions.the only evidence of Ubuntu is that you still have an entry in UEFI boot menu and /EFI/ubuntu folder in the ESP.  But grub in /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg wants to boot from a UUID that does not exist. And drive seems to be fully allocated, or no space where partition used to be. YOu may want to see what testdisk shows. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: When I live booted with Ubuntu, I can see the linux patition as well. Copied the data to a hard drive, and then formatted the drive. The problem I guess was when I moved the unallocated space, there were some overlap between my Ubuntu and Local Drive (300 gb). So when I ran test disk, I recovered Ubuntu but then my Local Disk went raw (even in Windows). So ultimately, I had to format it and reinstall everything.